# How can I decide weight in negative binomial regression?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm on my project to predict the amount of demand of products in a store.  We have lot of 0 on the amount of sales of products so when I did multiple regression, predictions of the demand had negative number and I got weird residual plot.

[image]

1. It has big difference between under 500 and over 500 in my plot.  I want to use weight to make nice residual plot.  But How can I decide weight?

   And I don't want negative predicted amount of demand.  So I used Negative binomial regression and poisson regression to prevent making negative number in prediction.  And I got some crazy residual plot.

   [image]
2. Can I keep using this binomial regression for prediction?
3. Could you recommend any other useful regression model?
4. If variance of data is bigger than mean of data, should I have to use quasi-poisson regression?

Comment: Is the apparent effect at about 500 because you are measuring demand in currency units and some products cost 500 currency units? It might be good to tell us what the predictors are (at least for those of us who do not read ?Korean?).

Comment: Can you edit the post so the im ages actually is shown, please?